# OnApplyTemplate never called in Custom Control

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I tested some codes about custom control but `OnApplyTemplate` is never called. I'm sure i have the correct static methods and assemblyInfo.cs setup; 
A whole version is inclued. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/n4uusow5z6ncd9c/AADMrI9jlr-qss7O2qyAg-5Aa?dl=0

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    Console.WriteLine("Begin");
    //get the part controls 
    PART_MasterGrid = GetTemplateChild("PART_MasterGrid") as Grid;
    PART_RightCntl = GetTemplateChild("PART_RightCntl") as StackPanel;
    PART_LeftCntl = GetTemplateChild("PART_LeftCntl") as StackPanel;
    PART_BottomCntl = GetTemplateChild("PART_BottomCntl") as StackPanel;
    PART_ParentPanel = GetTemplateChild("PART_ParentPanel") as DockPanel;
    //verify master grid exist
    if (PART_MasterGrid == null)
        return;
    //setup parent grid
    var parentGrid = new Grid();
    SetUpParentGrid(parentGrid);
    //set up layers
    var layer0 = Layers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Level == 0);
    if (layer0 == null)
        return;

    var columnLayers =
        Layers.Select(x => x).Where(x => x.Level > 0 && x.Orientation == Layer.LayerOrientation.Column).OrderBy(
                x => x.Level);
    var rowLayers =
        Layers.Select(x => x).Where(x => x.Level > 0 && x.Orientation == Layer.LayerOrientation.Row).OrderBy(x => x.Level);
    var item = SetupLayer0(layer0,
                               columnLayers,
                               rowLayers.Count());
    parentGrid.Children.Add(item);
    Grid.SetRow(item, 0);
    //setup the column grid layers
    if (columnLayers.Any())
    {
        foreach (var layer in columnLayers)
        {
            SetupColumnLayers(parentGrid, layer, columnLayers.Count());
        }
    }
    //setup the row grid layers
    if (rowLayers.Any())
    {
        foreach (var layer in rowLayers)
        {
            SetupRowLayers(item, layer, rowLayers.Count());
        }
    }

    //add parent grid to master grid
    PART_MasterGrid.Children.Add(parentGrid);
    Grid.SetRow(parentGrid, 0);
}
```

**Update**: I had the following `LayeredGrid.xaml` and had `Generic.xaml` to include `LayeredGrid.xaml`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type common:LayeredGrid}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" LastChildFill="True"
                           Name="PART_ParentPanel">
                    <StackPanel Name="PART_BottomCnt1" Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="AliceBlue"></StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Name="PART_LeftCnt1" Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="AliceBlue">
                        <StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                        </StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Name="PART_RightCnt1" Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Background="AliceBlue">
                        <StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                        </StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Grid Name="PART_MasterGrid" IsSharedSizeScope="True" Background="AliceBlue"></Grid>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Update2**: [Update2 has nothing to do with the above code as this version has Themes as a Root folder] In `MainWindow.xaml` gives a compiled error Cannot locate resource 'layeredgrid.xaml'.
    [image]

```
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel Name="DownStatusBar" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="AliceBlue">
        <Label></Label>
    </StackPanel>
    <testNest3:LayeredGrid>
        <testNest3:LayeredGrid.Layers>
            <testNest3:Layer Level="0">
                <testNest3:Layer.Content>
                    <Grid>
                        ...
                    </Grid>
                </testNest3:Layer.Content>
            </testNest3:Layer>
        </testNest3:LayeredGrid.Layers>
    </testNest3:LayeredGrid>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Perhaps the application never found a template to apply.  Do you have a default style defined in `Themes\generic.xaml`, and does that style set a `Template`?  Does the style have an implicit `x:Key`?  I can't see your files, as Dropbox is blocked at my office.

Comment: Are you overriding the default value for `DefaultStyleKeyProperty`?  You should call `OverrideMetadata` and specify a default value of `typeof(LayerGrid)`.

Comment: @MikeStrobel I believe I did everything u mentioned except `x:key`

Comment: You left off `x:Key`, which is what you're supposed to do; the key is implied.

Comment: See the addendum to my answer.  I believe I found your problem.

Comment: seems like I am late to see your post, BTW is there anything still needs clarification?

Comment: @pushpraj so far everything works fine;Ty;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things you need to check to make sure your default style gets applied:

1. Make sure you have an assembly-level `ThemeInfo` attribute and pass in  `ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly` for the second argument (`genericDictionaryLocation`):

   ```cs
   [assembly: ThemeInfo(
       ResourceDictionaryLocation.None,
       ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly)]
   ```
2. Make sure you have a `Themes\generic.xaml` resource dictionary in the same assembly as your custom control, with a Build Action of "Page".  Note that `Themes` must be a top-level folder in your project.
3. Make sure you override the default style key for your custom control in a static constructor:

   ```
   static LayerGrid() {
       DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
           typeof(LayerGrid),
           new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(LayerGrid)));
   }
   ```
4. Make sure your `generic.xaml` includes (either directly or through dictionary merging) a `Style` with a `TargetType` matching your custom control.  It should not have an explicit `x:Key`, and it should set the `Template` property.  If you pull your style in through `MergedDictionaries`, make sure to use assembly-qualified URIs when merging in other dictionaries, e.g.:

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary Source="/test_nest3;component\Themes/LayeredGrid.xaml" />
   ```

If you've verified everything above and are still having problems, check your output window to make sure there isn't some sort of error happening that might prevent the style from being applied.  Also, check the obvious: is the control actually getting loaded into the visual tree somewhere?

---

**EDIT:** I was able to open your project on my phone, and it seems your `Themes` folder is in the wrong location: it must be directly under your project, but you have it nested under a `Common` folder.  The location is supposed to be relative to the assembly root, not the folder containing the file where your control is defined.

Comment: I include a Common folder because it looks like if I make it a root `Themes` folder with `Generic.xaml` and `LayeredGrid.xaml`, The `mainWindow.xaml` can not locate `layergrid.xaml`, so I create a `Common` Folder to include `Themes` Folder and `LayeredGrid.cs`

Comment: It has to be a top-level folder, no way around that.  What do you mean when you say the `MainWindow.xaml` can't locate `LayerGrid.xaml`?  If you're getting an error when you put `Themes` in the right location, that at least suggests it found the file and is *trying* to load it.  Move `Themes` to the top level and let's work from there.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/99c2jj7a2gcl2cq/AACxAxaEccHS_CAfASiHBH1Pa?dl=0 Above is the version with the compiled error I mentioned. I could share a google drive if you wish.

Comment: Can you post the exact error?  If it's an exception, include the stack trace and complete `InnerException` if available.

Comment: In your merged dictionaries where you pull in `LayeredGrid.xaml`, try using an assembly-qualified path in `Source`: `/test_nest3;component\Themes/LayeredGrid.xaml`.

Comment: Problem solved by using so called `relative path`. Why this happened? I never payed attention to these detailed things such as `Source="pack://application:,,,...`

Comment: I'm honestly not sure why it's required in this context.  In theory, a simple path of `LayeredGrid.xaml` should be evaluated relative to the containing file's base URI, but it seems that's not the case (for generic/theme dictionaries at least).  I find it useful to always use "long" relative URIs just in case.